# Typeahead not working with tagsinput

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using [tagsinput](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) to create tags which can be chosen from with the [typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) library. The problem is that the typeahead won't show. I'm using a promise to see if the initialize is working and it does, the tagsinput is also working (with some strange behaviour).

So I don't really know what the problem is. I know theses libraries aren't kept up to date but they should work.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/krfwaryh/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tags">Tags</label>
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var cities = ["Amsterdam", "Washington", "New York"];


    var citynames = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: cities
    });

    var promise = citynames.initialize();
    promise
        .done(function () { console.log('ready to go!'); })
        .fail(function () { console.log('err, something went wrong :('); });

    $('#tags').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
            name: 'citynames',
            displayKey: 'name',
            valueKey: 'name',
            source: citynames.ttAdapter()
        }
    });

});
```